# Adding units in axis

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, graph, matlab-figure

Is there a library in python to include symbols in graphs using matplotlib?
I want my y-axis to represent Velocity in micrometer per second, which should have y-axis as V (µm/s). 
I am not able to insert in my code "micro" symbol. 
Currently I am plotting as V(um/s).

```
plt.ylabel('V (um/s)', fontsize = 10)
```

Comment: `µ` is even part of the ASCII, so it can be used as is, just like other Unicode symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
plt.ylabel('V (\u03BCm/s)')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! This worked! Can you please give me an URL for other symbols (if it is available).

Comment: As a quick google, I used this page... I am sure there is better more permanent pages out there.  https://pythonforundergradengineers.com/unicode-characters-in-python.html

Comment: Thanks again! this is helpful.